# Understanding Cookies and Claims for authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, claims-based-identity

I have been trying to understand the full process for the Cookie stored for ASP.net authentication and how they relate to the User Claim, and how it is made available in ASP.net to utilize for the User Context.

Looking at using the [app.UseCookieAuthentication()] middle-ware in ASP.net, and injecting [CookieAuthenticationOptions] to configure the implementation for Auth I have the following questions:

Regarding the cookie process and details stored inside the cookie, I do think the Cookie essentially contains details pertaining to the user - but I am not sure how those are reutilized to provide details to the [HttpContext.User.Identity] class.
Looking over the following article:  https://aspnetcore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security/authentication/cookie.html
I am just not sure how it knows that the UserId from [HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId()] belongs to the value added to the cookie for mapping those values (or if that is even the case...  I may just be thinking about it wrong, not sure...)

- The details of the cookie are customized for what is stored in the Cookie by creating a 'Ticket' *(which I am still unclear of why it is needed)*, and then this somehow provides ability to access user details through [HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId()], but I am not seeing how they relate to each other - so I was hoping that I could get some insight from some more familiar with the process.
  I have searched endlessly without real clear understanding of how the process all comes together.

The article from the link above mentions:  "the process recreates the principal and assigns it to the User property on HttpContext", so I am thinking that is what goes on, just can't seem to find the link about how that 'happens', still something in the mix that I am not understanding and left to draw conclusions about.)

What am I missing or not understanding in the process - how does everything relate to each other in the cycle for providing Auth?  Do they somewhere share a schema or something that they both utilize to know what the identified user model is defined as or something?

Any help or insight to help clear up my understanding is appreciated.  Thank you so much.